# What makes virtual functions so slow? C++

Tags: c++, function, refactoring, virtual

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Virtual functions and performance - C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449827/virtual-functions-and-performance-c)

I'm trying to refactor my code, and everywhere people say that using virtual functions is a huuuuge nono performance-wise, why? and is there another way that I can inherit a class and redefine functions that are defined in the base class?

Comment: Do you actually have a performance issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good reference article for this topic can be found here: http://coldattic.info/shvedsky/pro/blogs/a-foo-walks-into-a-bar/posts/3

For the lazy, I guess the answer is "maybe slower slightly"

Answer (score 1):

Virtual functions are called through a [vtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table), which is basically an array of function pointers.  So, every time one is called, there's an extra array lookup.  I'm not sure if I'd call this a *huuuuge* nono though, in general they should be pretty fast.

From **Wikipedia**:

> A virtual call requires at least an extra indexed dereference, and
>   sometimes a "fixup" addition, compared to a non-virtual call, which is
>   simply a jump to a compiled-in pointer. Therefore, calling virtual
>   functions is inherently slower than calling non-virtual functions. An
>   experiment done in 1996 indicates that approximately 6–13% of
>   execution time is spent simply dispatching to the correct function,
>   though the overhead can be as high as 50%.[4] The cost of virtual
>   functions may not be so high on modern CPU architectures due to much
>   larger caches and better branch prediction.

Comment: That's implementation defined, but most implementations do it that way.

Comment: I would also guess compilers have come a long way since 1996 :)