# C++ : Should we init class from parent or call directly class?

Tags: c++, class, oop, abstract

[edited for C++]I am not sure when I should create class directly or using parent to init.
Example :

**class A : class B**

USING :

**1)

A* a = new A();


2)

B* a = new A();**



Because of project 's requirement, I have to use number 2 . But I wonder what is better for performance ???
And if the performance of number 2 is bad, I will consider to using number 1 with a longer code :(

I think this is a good answer :
[Virtual functions and performance - C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449827/virtual-functions-and-performance-c)

Comment: You want to talk about mechanisms of two different languages at once?

Comment: Hi LogicStuff, I write both code C++ and Java for windows and android. So I have to write 2 languages depend on that idea.

Comment: Please pick a language.  C++ is not Java.  Just because there is a keyword `new` in both languages doesn't mean one is the same as the other.

Comment: The code is not valid C++.  The `new` in C++ returns a pointer, not an object.  Also, post what `A` and `B` are.  If there is hardly a difference, and if for some reason, constructing a `B` does something ridiculously slow, there isn't going to be any difference that you would notice if you used `new B`.  Also, you write code that is understandable first.

Answer (score 2):

*Number 2* harnesses the power of **polymorphism**. It gives you the ability to instantiate objects & assign them to a **super-class** reference type.

This way if you have a third class `C` that inherits from the abstract class `A`, you could do such thing as:

```
class B : A
class C : A

A* bObj = new B();
A* cObj = new C();
```

For performance comparisons, check this link:
[C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449827/virtual-functions-and-performance-c)

Comment: I want to know that what is better for performance. I think when we use number 2, there are 2 memory space created for instance of A and B.
But If we init by using A a = new A(); => just instance of A is created. Because of project 's requirement, I have to use number 2 !

Comment: That 's nice,Sparta !!