# C++ Pass dynamic allocated objects of abstract type to function and store in vector

Tags: c++, vector, abstract-class, dynamic-memory-allocation, unique-ptr

On the caller side, I want to pass arbitrary objects of a specific super class via stream operator:

```cpp
class SubclassA : public Superclass { ... }
class SubclassB : public Superclass { ... } 

...

Container container;
container << SubclassA(param1, param2) << SubclassB(param);
```

On the callee side, I have to store all passed objects in a vector or list:

```cpp
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Superclass>> childs;
Container & operator<<(Superclass const & child) {
  childs.emplace_back(new Superclass(child)); // not possible, since Superclass is abstract 
  return *this;
}
```

Are there any possibilities to keep the desired behaviour on the callee side, avoiding the need of `std::unique_ptr` or `new` keyword?

**Edit**:
Add missing `&` in stream operator parameter.

Comment: You could always use `std::shared_ptr` and `std::make_shared` or in the case you showed `std::make_unique`, right? Or you want to avoid smart pointer by any chance?

Comment: If possible, I would like to avoid smart pointers completely, but only **on the caller side**. Since this stream function is called very often, it would be much cleaner, if I could pass raw objects as shown in the example.

Comment: @NutCracker Using a `shared_ptr` where a `unique_ptr` suffices is always a bad idea.

Comment: @JaMiT, although the answer to the referenced question is the same to this answer, the questions are still quite different. IMHO, the two questions are no duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add two things to make this work.

First, `operator<<` *needs* to take its parameter by reference.  Otherwise you have [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

Second, you need to add a virtual `clone` method to `Superclass` that is implemented by all the derived classes.  This method would make a copy of itself and return the pointer to it.

```
class Superclass {
public:
    virtual Superclass *clone() const;  // optionally can be abstract
    // ...
};

Container & operator<<(Superclass const &child) {
  childs.emplace_back(child.clone());
  return *this;
}

class SubclassA : public Superclass {
    SubclassA *clone() const override {
        return new SubclassA(*this);
    }
};
```

This relies on the creation of unique_ptrs from pointers.  Since any type of raw pointer is discouraged these days, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54446402/5231607) for a way to overcome the limitation that smart pointers and covariant return types don't get along and use `unique_ptr` directly.

Comment: Thank you! First issue was a typo, second solution fits perfectly.